# Cannot open GUI from docker container

Tags: ubuntu, x11, docker

i am trying to run some gui tests on a docker container, i am able to run it on a headless browser with the help of xvbf and exporting the DISPLAY variable to some unused port like 99

Now i want to forward the X11 to host machine and see the browser,
for that, i did

```
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix <image id> /bin/bash
```

inside the container, i just tried to start firefox.

But i am getting the following error.

```
Client is not authorized to connect to Servererror: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment
Error: cannot open display:  :1.0
```

Comment: Can you show me your Xvfb command? Does $DISPLAY contain the display number you create with Xvfb? It seems to me you are sharing host display instead of Xvfb display.

Comment: I used the following commands,

Xvfb :99 -ac &   

export DISPLAY=:99

ref: https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2

Like you said, i executed this inside the docker container. 
at least i need a way to see the browser outside by using something like X11 forwarding.

Comment: Your error messages says `:1.0` instead of `:99`. With `-ac` you don't need XAUTHORITY. `docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=:99  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix <image id> /bin/bash` should work.

Comment: You also can use [x11docker to run GUI applications in docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)